# Remove a UIView stored in an array from superview

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uiimageview, swift2

I know the code I need is `[[Array objectAtIndex:index] removeFromSuperview];` but that doesn't work in Swift 2.

I'm trying to remove a UIView stored in an array from the superview. I know I want to remove the object at index 0. Want to remove it at the end of the for loop. 
What code will work in Swift?

import UIKit
import Foundation

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
var tileStack = [AnyObject]()
let num = 0


//Beginning of simple image selection and display

@IBOutlet weak var displayImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tiledView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func choosePicFromLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
    }
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

    if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
        imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
    }
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    displayImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage!
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



//Beginning of function to cut photo into 9 tiles, then display them randomly.

//cut selected image into 9 pieces and add each cropped image to tileStack array

@IBAction func randomize(sender: AnyObject) {


let selectedImageWidth = displayImageView.image!.size.width
let selectedImageHeight = displayImageView.image!.size.height

let tileSize = CGSizeMake(selectedImageWidth/3, selectedImageHeight/3)

    for (var colI = 0; colI < 3; colI++)
    {
        for (var rowI = 0; rowI < 3; rowI += 1)
        {
            let tileRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(rowI) * tileSize.width, tileSize.height * CGFloat(colI), tileSize.width, tileSize.height)

            if let selectedImage = displayImageView.image
            {
                let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(selectedImage.CGImage, tileRect)
                let aUItile = UIImage(CGImage: tileImage!)
                tileStack.append(aUItile)
            }

        }
    }


    //display tiles in order on screen, remove 1 tile (top left, index 0), (eventually mix them up)
    let frameWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let frameHeight = self.view.frame.height

    var xCen = (frameWidth/3)/2
    var yCen = (frameHeight/3)/2

    var pieceNumber = 0


    for (var v = 0; v < 3; v += 1)
    {
        for (var h = 0; h < 3; h += 1)
        {
            var tiledView : UIImageView
            tiledView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth/3, (frameHeight)/3))
            //tiledView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            tiledView.center = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
            tiledView.image = tileStack[pieceNumber] as? UIImage
            tiledView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            self.view.addSubview(tiledView)
            xCen += (frameWidth/3)
            pieceNumber += 1
        }
        xCen = (frameWidth/3)/2
        yCen += (frameHeight/3)
    }
    tileStack[0].removeFromSuperview()
    tileStack.removeAtIndex(0)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0, you need to call the removeFromSubview from the object that you want to remove. In your case you need the following:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
{
    if self.view.subviews.count > 0
    {
      self.view.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
    }
})

Comment: I tried using `tileStack[0].removeFromSuperview()` but the app crashed and took me to the AppDelegate line (see screenshot I added above). You mentioned SUBview first—should I be using that?

Comment: you need to remove these lines:
 tileStack[0].removeFromSuperview()
    tileStack.removeAtIndex(0)

Comment: Okay I get: "Value of type 'PhotoViewController' has no member "subviews"

Comment: I updated my answer and added some checking. Can you also post the rest of your code so that I will have better understanding of your code. thanks.

Comment: it should be self.view.subviews. It would have been faster if you posted other codes as I don't know the context.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. I added all the code for the 9-piece sliding tile puzzle game I'm trying to create. Trying to remove 1 tile so I can slide the other 8 pieces around.

Comment: did you try my updated answer? That should fix your problem.

Comment: yes I tried that but it didn't remove the tile/puzzle piece/UIView.

Comment: try call removeFromSuperview in NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock

Comment: I updated my answer and put the code inside a dispatch_async. Please try it.

Comment: @ChristianAbella 
I realized I was only storing UIImages in an array, not their UIImageViews. So, I couldn't remove a UIImageView from an array because I never made an array to store them! Problem solved.